# django foreign key relation lookup

Tags: python, django, foreign-key-relationship

Given the following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    html = models.TextField()

class PostTag(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey('Post')
    tag = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to accomplish looking up a Post based on a given PostTag. So if I had two posts, A and B, tagged as "foo", I want to be able to look up all posts with that tag and get the posts A and B back.

I image the query would look something like the following:

```
posts = Post.objects.filter(tag=tag)
```

Any tips on where to start to accomplish this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Close. You need to specify which field [you're spanning across](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships).

```
Post.objects.filter(posttag__tag=tag)
```